# What is the best way to set AutoDeployment for Dot Net Nuke Web Site in TFS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, deployment, dotnetnuke

i am looking for a way to autodeploy a Dot Net Nuke website by TFS after checking in. I also need to some how transform web config to the right connection for the deploy server.

Since this is a website but not a web application, thing becomes tricky. If you have done it before, please give me some idea. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have not done auto deployment with TFS but did automate the process with SVN.  What we did is simply have the script deploy everything that had changed since last login to the web server - EXCEPT - the web.config.

Database scripts were handled by a process like this but those were not as reliable as the SVN code deployment was.

HTH

Comment: Hi, Could you show how's the script look like or point me to a site  that have some sample. --Jason

Comment: Jason - its just a vb windows app that is called every night about 8 pm - you will have to dig into the svn command line commands - I no longer work for the company so i dont have a copy of it any more - should be easy to recreate

Answer (score 1):

You could use a deployment tool such as [kwatee](http://www.kwatee.net) (self promotion). Kwatee is configured via a web GUI and can then deploy any application or site via python scripts and transform files along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio web deploy feature. ALM Rangers shipped a ready to use BRDLite Reference template for this purpose which you can download [here](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/releases/82962/download/347183). Also, check this [link](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/releases/82962/download/347182) for documentation for the template usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS2010, you can use a Web Deploy Project in your solution. TFS will talk to the WDP as it would with a web application's project file.

For config transforms, you can use a tool called SlowCheetah.